# How to work in the states $|F,m_F\rangle$ in hyperfine structure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, hyperfine-structure

Suppose that we have two atoms with one proton one electron each, and these electrons interact with each other. The states for the electrons are the singlet ($S=0$) and the triplet states ($S=1$). My question is if I have to keep the nuclear spin of the protons parallel when I write the states, for example $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|{+,-}\rangle-|{-,+}\rangle)_e\otimes|\!\uparrow\rangle_p$$
for the singlet state, and if so, can I use the fact that $F=S+I$, which in this case would yield the state $|1,1\rangle$?

($S=0,I=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1,m_s=0,m_I=1$)

Comment: What is $I$ here? What is $F$?